# How to avoid showering twice when cycling to and from work?

Tags: commuter

I'm at the stage where even a light cycle to/from work raises an appreciable sweat.

I shower when I get into work,  but I'm sweaty when I get home too. How do I avoid showering twice a day?

Comment: Is there no hygiene tag?

Comment: Work from home.

Comment: Get used to being a bit sweaty for a short while, you will not die from it. After a few minutes at home the dirty feeling of sweat should disapear. If not, train yourself to ignore it for a bit longer. Use deodorant in your armpits to avoid the dirty smell, ignore the rest, the human race is designed to sweat, very important in heat control.

Answer (score 0):

Very good antiperspirant for the morning ride can work, dressing as cool as possible and changing clothes when you get in. Everyone has an upper limit for effort/distance/temperature for which this works, and if you work at the top of a hill, forget it.

Slowing down for the last bit can help. You may even be able to take your helmet off for the last couple of hundred metres. This can make a big difference but only you can judge the riding conditions.

I *didn't* find that baby wipes made for a good freshen up.

Comment: I would be incredibly hesitant recommending helmet removal, even if it's only for a short distance.

Comment: @altonmr, here in the UK helmets are optional. I choose to wear one. After the last bend in the cul-de-sac I live in, I can see the whole of the rest of my route home, with no blind entrances. This last hundred metres is enough to make a big difference. (and besides, I test-ride on the same road without a helmet). Much as I'd like to, I don't do this arriving at the station, passing the taxi rank.

Comment: As soon as you stop riding (at the door to work) take off your helmet and coat and gloves.  If I walk my bike inside fully dressed, I start sweatting more.

Comment: Coat?! Only in significant rain or below freezing. Shorts and short sleeves above about 10C here. I've always had to keep the bike outside during the day, and even locking up in a fairly open shelter it makes a big difference keeping the helmet and gloves on. I also have a selection of gloves and pick the minimum that won't give me cold hands. (@Criggie)